# A mathematician from the outside looking in

Tags: neural-network, mathematics, kernel

I am wondering if anybody could give a survey of applications of approximation theory to data science. One application I am familiar with are, for example, wavelet neural networks. Does anybody know of similar such applications/inspirations from approximation theory or numerical analysis (polynomial & rational approximation, wavelet analysis) to data science, perhaps specifically to neural networks, or kernel methods?